# Reloading Expo app logs out Firebase User

Tags: firebase, expo

I have an Expo app that I am building that uses Firebase.  I have the following code that handles when a user's auth state changes.  When it changes, it sets a context property and shows a specific stack dependent on the status of the user.

```
export default function RootNavigator() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeAuthStateChanged = getAuth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticatedUser) => {
      if (authenticatedUser) setUser(authenticatedUser);
      else setUser(null);
      setIsLoading(false);

      console.log(authenticatedUser);
    });

    return unsubscribeAuthStateChanged;
  }, [user]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }

  return <NavigationContainer>{user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}</NavigationContainer>;
}
```

However, when I reload the expo app by pressing "R" in the terminal, my firebase user is null again.

I am using the following code to log a user in:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailAddress, password).catch((error) => handleSignInError(error));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!